# Limit selection to visible not working?

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting

Limit selection to visible not working?
No matter if i tick it or not, I can't paint through my mesh. http://prntscr.com/muinpy As you can see in this pic, I have it ticked, and the same thing happens if I don't, The vertecies on his belt are still light blue after I try to paint them, since no matter what I do my weight paint won't go through the mesh.

Comment: Hi. Please upload images using the built-in uploader. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: perhaps share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)